# MVC form Value not passed to JavaScript when using bootstrap to hide and show field

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to passed the value from the MVC form to JavaScript. I am using bootstrap to hide and show field. when I remove the bootstrap hide and show functionality on the form I will get the value in the message box but when the Hide/Show is enable I cannot get the value as shown by the image below. can anyowne tell me where I am going wrong

[image]

HTML

```
      @using (Html.BeginForm("SearchPatient","HOME", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
      {
         @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.Label("Search Criteria", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label  col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                         @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SearchCriteria,
                         new List<SelectListItem> {
                         new SelectListItem { Value = "" , Text = "Select Search Criteria" },
                          new SelectListItem { Value = "1" , Text = "Patient Id" },

                       }, new { @class = "form-control selectchosen" })

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group" id="PatientId" style="display:none">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PatientId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PatientId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control " } })    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group" id="AllShow" style="display:none">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-offset-2">
                                <input type="button" value="Search" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSubmit" onclick="Enablecontrols();" />

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>         
}
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $('#SearchCriteria').change(function () {
   if ($("#SearchCriteria").val() == 1) {
   $("#AllShow").show();
   $("#PatientId").show();
   ValidateField("PatientId", true);  
  }
function Enablecontrols() {
  $(document).ready(function () {

    var patientid = $("#PatientId").val();
   if ($("#SearchCriteria").val() == 1) {
        alert("I am an alert box! the patient number is" + patientid);
     }
   }
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

rather than use the show/hide methods of bootstrap, use toggle. It's more reliable.

If that doesn't work you can also use `$('#PatientId').css('display','block');`

Comment: I changed hide/show to   $('#PatientId').css('display', 'block'); still cannot get PatientId in the alert message

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed  by changing the ID of the Div to dPatientId
Stupid mistake